# What is the fastest way to store one or more user-input images during runtime with their original dimensions for processing later?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, listview, image-resizing

I am writing a windows forms application in c# that resizes user-input images. I'm currently trying to add functionality that will allow the user to drag and drop one or more images onto the form, display these images in a list (more detail on current implementation below), then allow the user to click on an image on the list at which point the selected image will show up in a picturebox. With this, I will implement 'batch' resizing.

**Current implementation :**

- in the DragDrop event, populate a string array with the dropped files

  ```
      string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
  ```
- call 'areAllImages' method which iterates through each file in the string array and returns true if all files are valid image file types, else returns false
- if areAllImages == false, show an error messagebox

  ```
      if (areAllImages(files) == false)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Only files with .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .bmp and .png extensions are allowed. Check the file(s) you are attempting to import into the program.");
      }
  ```
- if areAllImages == true, run a few methods that do stuff with the interface (irrelevant to question), then iterate through the array, adding Bitmaps of the images in the array to an imageList and adding the imageList elements into a Listview (I named it imageListView) :

  ```
          int i = 0;

          foreach (string element in files) //files == string array containing my image files
          {
              string fileName = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
              Bitmap img = new Bitmap(files[i]);
              imageList1.Images.Add("Image" + i, img);
              imageListView.Items.Add(fileName, i);
              i++;
          }
  ```
- I then have an event handler for the ListView that shows whatever item was selected in the ListView in a PictureBox (Named imgBox). Ignore the updatePreviewer and updateDimensions methods - they are irrelevant.

  ```
  private void imageListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      foreach (ListViewItem item in imageListView.SelectedItems)
      {
          int imgIndex = item.ImageIndex;
          if (imgIndex >= 0 && imgIndex < this.imageList1.Images.Count)
          {
              Bitmap img = new Bitmap(this.imageList1.Images[imgIndex]);
              procedures.updatePreviewer(img, imgBox);
              updateDimensions(img, heightLabel, widthLabel);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This works - **but**, the images that get shown in the PictureBox (imgBox) are 16x16 px. I know that this is because the ImageList imageSize is set to 16x16, but I can't find a way to store the drag and dropped image(s) with its/their original dimensions. The maximum is 256, and I'm going to have to allow inputting images much much larger than that.

**Question :** How could I manipulate this implementation to show images with their original dimensions? If it is not possible/feasible, what are some alternative ways that I could store these images so that I can access them through some sort of list container and show them in a PictureBox with their original dimensions?

Thank you

Comment: You can add some abstraction: `class MyImage` with `Image` (use to store dragged image and process it later, better idea is just to remember the path and don't use memory) and [`Thumbnail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbnail) (used to display image in the list, 16x16 or whatever size you prefer, can be a setting).

Comment: Alright, I'll play around with this and see if I can get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding an array to hold all the filepaths of the imported images and instead of loading the image from the listview index, I load images from the path at the array index equivalent to the item clicked